# I need a MOSFET gate driver for Synchronous boost DC-DC converter circuit

Tags: power, mosfet, analog, boost, driver

I have designed a Synchronous boost DC-DC converter with two N-Chanel MOSFETs. But I can not find a proper gate driver for my circuit. I'm looking for a driver that will turn off one mosfet while the other is on. I'm also considering using a PWM as the driver's input signal. Can you help me on this matter? [image]

Comment: M3 is connected backwards; the source of the sync fet should be on the switch node, not the drain.

Comment: I didn't understand what you said, can you please explain in more detail?

Comment: As drawn, the circuit is liable to destroy FETs. You need to swap the source and drain of M3.

Comment: This is not my circuit, just a schematic found on the web. I definitely paid attention to this in my own circuit. I'm just looking for a driver, thank you very much for your interest.

Comment: @Hearth, M3 is a PMOS and bulk is connected to the load which will be at a higher potential. So, I am not sure if there is an issue.

Comment: @aork - Hi, (a) You said: "*This is not my circuit, just a schematic found on the web*". In order to comply with the Stack Exchange [rule for referencing](/help/referencing), please [edit] the question & add a link to the webpage which was the original source for the schematic. (b) Please see the main site rules in the [tour] & [help] as they differ from typical forums. Thanks.

Comment: @sai I missed that it was p-channel. You never see people use p-channel FETs for power converters, so it didn't even occur to me to check.

Comment: @Hearth - Hi, It's even more understandable not to expect a P-channel FET, since the *schematic* contradicts the question *text* which says: "*I have designed a Synchronous boost DC-DC converter with two N-Chanel MOSFETs*" :(